# Yii2: how to find by other field in a GridView instead of id field?

Tags: php, gridview, text, yii2, primary-key

I use GridView to show a model called **Relatives** (familiars of a person) that have two fields: **Person** (attribute id_person) and **Relative** (attribute name_relative).

The tables of my database are Persons and Relatives.

I have a problem with the Person field. I don't show the ids of persons, instead I show the names of persons because the id is an auto generated primary key.

When I the user wants to search, it is searched by id_person. **I need to search typing a name of a person**, nobody will write an id.

Here is the code of the RelativesController file:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        [
            'attribute' => 'id_person',
            'label' => 'Person',
            'value' => function($model) {
                $person = \app\models\Persons::findOne(['id_person' => $model->id_person]);
                return $person->name_person;
            }
        ],
        'name_relative',
    ],
]); ?>
```

This is what I have (searching by **id**):
[image: Seaching by id]

This is what I need (searching by **name**):
[image: Searching by name]

Comment: update your question and add  the controller/Action too

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-data-widgets.html#working-with-model-relations

Comment: Why are you showing name in id attribute? If you have name field in Persons you can directly use that.

Comment: @Chinmay: I corrected the question because I have two tables. The name  that I need is from the other table.